# in networkx minimum_node_cut returns an empty array, whereas node_connectivity returns a length of 6

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

i have been trying to find out the minimum number of nodes to block communication between all the central nodes and one of the peripheral nodes in a MultiDiGraph. 
However, minimum_node_cut keeps returning an empty array. Node_connectivity on the other hand returns an integer 6.

What might explain this?

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]?